# Android: Image processing library for cropping, auto straightening, rotation

Tags: android, picasso

I am reviewing Picasso and other image processing libraries for a) cropping, b) rotation and c) auto straightening.
I understand from [Google Photos App style Image Cropping, Straightening and panning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617081/google-photos-app-style-image-cropping-straightening-and-panning) that picasso can be used for cropping, but it doesn't answer other parts of my question.

Can some one point me to any library that supports auto straightening and rotation of image (or does Picasso supports it already, which I am not sure?)

Comment: You can use OpenCV for all image processing techniques.But this library is written in C/C++.If you have knowledge about native side, you can use this.

Comment: @JavadKhan told you use native or Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666379/image-straightening-in-android-sample

Comment: you can also use adobe sdk for android for this.https://creativesdk.adobe.com/